What is the best way to insulate an above-ground cold room?
Our cold room is located under the front porch of our three-storey townhouse. It opens up into our utility room and does not currently have a door or insulation.
None of the walls are below ground. The interior wall is cinder block and the exterior cladding is brick.
The walls have been painted, but the paint is peeling off and the cinder blocks are wet to the touch after it rains. It has had water issues in the past which have been mitigated by some caulking work done on the porch.
I would like to insulate the cold room as it is very humid in the summer (the ceiling drips with condensation) and freezing in the winter.
However, I am leery about insulating the interior of the room before resolving any moisture infiltration issues. The surface of the porch and the exterior brick cladding is not sealed with any sealant or repellant.
I was looking at 2” closed cell spray foam, but am worried that the moisture issues and previous paint jobs will create problems down the road.

Solve the moisture issues first.

And some photos would sure help us understand what you're dealing with...

Insulation will help if no water leaks.  You also need ventilation to let cooler air in and warmer air out.  Condensation happens when warm humid air touches a cool/cold surface, so insulation will help there.

Insulate the exterior. Closed cell foam can be used as a waterproof roofing material. Done properly, it's insulated and the rain doesn't come in. Of course, we don't know how complicated or easy it will be to treat the roof of the room that's under the floor of the porch...
